# Turn off Admin Bar (Toolbar) in backend - no easy way

Tags: plugin-development, admin-bar, xml-rpc

I'm working on a theme for the back end Admin pages, this is for a custom web application built on WP.

After studying `admin-bar.php` and the function `is_admin_bar_showing()` for a few minutes I decided to do this:

```
function kill_admin_toolbar() {
    add_filter( 'xmlrpc_enabled', '__return_false' );
    define( 'XMLRPC_REQUEST', false );
}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'kill_admin_toolbar' );
```

I never plan on using XML-RPC with this application.

With this code there is no more 32px strip of immovable toolbar at the top of my admin screen.

I can't see any weird side effects so far; what do you guys think?

It's either this or I modify `admin-bar.php` and insert `return false;` right after the function definition for `is_admin_bar_showing()`.  The idea of touching even one core file really bothers me, though.

Really maddening there is no hook early enough in that function to do this.

Comment: I haven't looked into this properly yet, but would CSS be suitable for you? It'll at least have no unknown side effects :)

Comment: thanks...yeah I played around with css, looked at several examples of how other people were tackling this -- nothing was really great.  I could also easily load some JS that removes the entire element from the DOM, but I really wanted to find something in PHP that worked.  I kind of like my solution - if it doesn't cause any other problems ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While what you used appears to work for now, I couldn't guarantee it isn't going to cause other issues now or in the future because - as you already know - tricking `is_admin_bar_showing()` isn't what the check of the `XMLRPC_REQUEST` constant was designed for. Therefore even if it doesn't cause issues now I don't think it would future-proof to use it like this.

However, I continued your hunt and **I think I've found the filter you need: [`wp_admin_bar_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_admin_bar_class/)**.

Returning false to this filter - or returning any string that doesn't match the name of a defined class - [will cause `_wp_admin_bar_init()` to short-circuit](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/admin-bar.php#L10) and thus never initialize the bar in the first place:

```
add_filter( 'wp_admin_bar_class', '__return_false' );
```

This works, but is unfortunately giving me a nice blank gap where the admin bar used to be, because of the `wp-toolbar` CSS class being present on the dashboard's `<html>` tag. This is added in [wp-admin/includes/template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php#L1937) and I can't immediately see a way to remove it in the PHP. So, you'd probably need to override this padding with custom CSS (sorry, maybe a PHP-only solution isn't possible after all!):

```
add_action( 'admin_head', function(){
  ?><style> html.wp-toolbar { padding-top: 0; } </style><?php
});
```

---

There may be other slight hiccups as a result of removing the admin bar like this, given that `is_admin_bar_showing()` still technically returns true, but I *think* they would be fairly minor, and if you find any, it probably wouldn't be too difficult to find a workaround.

To be sure (for now at least), you could hunt through the source for any usages of the function. As of 4.5.3, usage appears to be limited to four files: [admin-header.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-admin/admin-header.php), [template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-admin/includes/template.php), [admin-bar.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/admin-bar.php), and [post-template.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/post-template.php), and from a cursory glance it appears you might want to filter [`admin_body_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/) to remove 'admin-bar' from there too, just in case (it's not making a visible difference for me though).

See also the 'no-customize-support' class - I don't think this will affect you, because [it appears to be designed](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22052) only for 'hide-if-no-customize' menu options in the toolbar... which of course you're not displaying anyway!

Comment: thanks Tim, I will try this out tonight.  Pretty sure I did try inoculating `wp_admin_bar_class` -- but will look at it again.  I'd love it if whoever actually gets to do dev on core would add a hook to `is_admin_bar_showing()`, earlier in the function.  Seems like a zero-risk thing to do...

Comment: @CC You can log a trac ticket for that if you like :)

Comment: heh - ok thanks; I've never even looked into that before so might be an interesting learning experience!